# Provide example of abstract class in small embedded system

Tags: c++, embedded

I am a C++ newbie.

When to create abstract class in small embedded system.

When i say small embedded system, i mean an embedded system which perform some Analog input reading (using ADC) and perform some signal/logic processing and perform digital IO operations.

Please suggest some cases or refer some text where i can learn on the abstract class usage in such embedded systems.

EDIT: Thanks for giving example on what an abstract class is and i am well aware of it, with example of calculate area of a different shape. I was looking for examples of real scenario from experts who had to use abstract class in embedded systems for may be any device driver to make code better and smarter. No problem if there is no such case.

Comment: Are you sure you need an abstract class? On small devices its often better to choose static polymorphism.

Comment: How is an abstract classon a small embedded system different from any other abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between abstract class in ES or in any other system. It's just a tool for creating and providing communication interface between classes.  [Here is a fine example of how abstract classes work](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interfaces.htm).

Comment: Well, there is a slight difference and that is on small embedded systems, it is usually fine to make such abstract classes singleton and non re-entrant. Meaning you can just dump all private data at file scope, as `static`.

Comment: A fair point, thanks mate.